# how to unset and/or update git http credentials previously saved?

Tags: git

I have used `git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=360000'` before to store git credentials for an http only git repository. But my credentials have changed and I am unable to change it. I have tried:

1. `git config --system --unset credential.helper`
2. `git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=1'`
3. `git config --global --unset user.password`

but every time I do a `git pull` I get

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 
'https://SAVED-USERNAME:SAVEDPASSWORD@sourcecodeexampleurl.com/repo.git'`
```

Comment: I thought it was, git remote-v did not have the credentials. However, I changed the URL and changed it back and now it's working ..

Answer (score 0):

#### Why not switching to ssh?

With ssh, you don't need any credentials at all

#### To update your credentials, go to

```
Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> Generic Credentials.
```

If it's not found under the Credential manager search for it under **User Accounts**

Comment: disabled by our management.  and no control panel. Sorry should have mentioned it mac osx. It's fixed now.